# Flexslider ignores animationLoop: True

Tags: javascript, css, flexslider

So I have a slider made with Flexslider 2

In the Javascript file from flexslider I changed :

```
animationLoop: true,
```

And my slider initialization looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('#flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    itemWidth: 155,
    itemMargin: 5,
    pausePlay: true,
    minItems: 6,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

And my slider just wont make that loop, when you get to the last slide/first if you hit for the next slide it will rewind back to the first / last  post without making that animation loop so it seems it's a continue string of images.

Any ideas how i can solve it ?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the test-site or perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry cannot give out link, and i dont know why a JSFiddle would be needed, because there is all the javascript for it, dont think a html command can modify the animationLoop

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: seems to be related to [report on github](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/331). The same is happening when sync and animationLoop are both set.

Answer (score 0):

Set the animationLoop back to `false` and change the `animation` to `fade`.

This way you will still have the same feel without sliding.

Comment: this is a carousel, if you put fade with animationLoop false, this will only show just one item not all of them, plus i dont want the animation to be "fade", i need "slide"

Comment: Well then you have a problem because why do you think the author specifically disables the `animationLoop` setting in the demo page. There are continuous problems with that setting and it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: If it's continuous string of images you need then perhaps [this](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html) will help you out.